# Changing widthstep of image opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on project related to face recognition. For my program to work each image should satisfy the condition `img->widthStep = 3 * img->width`.

I am trying my code on database in which each image is of size 250x250. But the widthstep for the database is 752 hence the above condition does not satisfy. The function of widthstep is in accessing the pixel (http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/What-is-widthstep-td2679559.html).

Can I change the widthstep parameter to 750 without affecting other parameters of image?
Or else is there other way to achieve the condition `zimg->widthStep = 3 * img->widthz`?

I tried copying the 250x250 to 260x260 image as follows

```
Mat img1, img2=Mat::zeros(Size(260,260),CV_8UC3);
img1 = imread(ch);
img1.copyTo(img2.colRange(1,250).rowRange(1,250));
```

But it shows this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed 
    (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() =
    = Size(cols, rows)) in unknown function, file D:\opencv2.4.5\opencv\modules\core
    \src\matrix.cpp, line 1372
```

Can anyone help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: have a look at this: http://answers.opencv.org/question/22742/create-a-memory-continuous-cvmat-any-api-could-do/

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you are using term widthStep I guess you are using IplImage. IplImage was taken from Intel Performance Primitives (IPP) library. In order to have good performance it is required  that widthStep of each row should be multiple of 4. To enforce this condition rows are padded with addition bytes. So as long as you are using IplImage you won't be able to have widthStep equal to 750 which is not multiple of 4.
2. OpenCV 1 was based on IplImage, but OpenCV 2 is based on Mat. Its been a years since IplImage was deprecated.
3. Mat has no such limitation. By default its step will be 750.

**After edit of the question**:

colRange(1,250) means 249 columns, not 250. Same for rowRange(1,250). When size of the image being copied is different from size of target image, target image is reallocated. But since colRange and rowRange return constant temporary image it can't be reallocated and the program crashes.